# How to make a correct mosaic with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a common problem that I never know how to solve with CSS:

In this example: http://cssdesk.com/5s6eH

How can I get 3 `li` per line while keeping `ul` and `li` width and 10px between `li`?

Edit: I am looking for a generic solution that does not requires to know the number of columns in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

nth-child magic. Probably won't work in older versions of IE.

```
li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

http://cssdesk.com/p4VTX

Comment: I'am sorry, my question wasn't complete. I am looking for a generic solution that does not requires to know the number of columns in advance. But your solution is really good and I will probably use it if I can't find a generic one.

Answer (score 0):

You would obviously have to specify which elements you don't want to have margins. You need to know in advanced how many list elements you'll have and how many columns you want, which from your question you seem to. Unless you're very lucky you won't have access to new CSS rule selectors like `n'th` childs etc. for all your clients. If you do, then the other answer here is 'better'.

Then it's a matter of adding another CSS rule:

```
.last {
  margin-right:0;
}
```

And specifying the last column elements:

```
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="last"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="last"></li>
</ul>
```

http://cssdesk.com/bBx5y

Comment: Actually, I am looking for a generic solution that does not requires to know the number of columns in advance. I edited my question. Sorry